# Python запуск консольной программы

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь написать программу на python, которая бы запускала консольную программ, вот её код

```
import subprocess

print ("Start program")
cmd = r'/home/user/prog/tool/bin/resample -p param.prm  '
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
```

param.prm - текстовый файл, где есть перечень параметров, -p - параметр.
Когда запускаю программу, вроде бы всё нормально происходит, но появляется ошибка

```
Error: ReadParameterFile : Opening Input Parameter File
 : Unable to open parameter file param.prm
Fatal Error, Terminating...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  в чём проблема и как её побороть.

Comment: Проверьте (1) где программа ищет входной файл, и если в текущем каталоге, то (2) какой каталог для неё текущий на момент запуска.

Comment: А где этот файл находится? Попробуйте для начала указать полный путь к нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проверьте (1) где программа ищет входной файл, и если в текущем каталоге, то (2) какой каталог для неё текущий на момент запуска.

Большое спасибо, Вы правы, исправил вот так

```
cmd = r'/home/user/prog/tool/bin/resample -p /home/user/prog/tool/bin/param.prm  '
```

и заработало.