# Python CGI, запуск сторонней программы

Tags: python, cgi

Добрый день! Недавно я уже спрашивал про запуск консольной программы посредством Python-a
[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189166/python-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Вот код программы которая получилась

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb 
import subprocess
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<title>Test CGI</title>"
print "<p>Hello World!</p>"
import subprocess

print ("Start program")


def startProgram(cmd):
  PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
  return p



cmd = r'/home/div/geotools/tool/bin/resample -p /home/div/geotools/tool/bin/convert.prm' 
startProgram(cmd)
```

Я пытаюсь запустить данную программу посредством браузера и CGI, если просто запускать её то всё хорошо, работает. Но если через браузер и cgi, то нет, я везде поставил права 777. В чём может быть проблема? Я что-то неправильно понимаю  про cgi?

Comment: А из этой диркетории, где cgi, какая-нибудь другая cgi запускается? Может httpd (кстати какой?) просто не знает, что программы оттуда запускать нужно.

Comment: то есть как я вас понимаю можно попробовать скопировать в папку cgi-bin программу, которую я хочу при помощи python-скрипта запускать, так?

Comment: Как вариант. Или описать директорию, где находится скрипт, как директорию с cgi. Если система -- unix-like,  то строка

      #!/usr/bin/python

должна указывать на интерпретатор питона. Если винды -- то ситуация несколько иная (надо смотреть)

Comment: OC Ubuntu, что-то по всякому пробую ни как не получается, прога вроде запускается, но пишет про какую-то директорию найти, хотя я уже всё перекопировал в cgi-bin и везде прописал пути, в консольном режиме python-скрипт всё прекрасно запускает...

Comment: И что же пишет? Или текст сообщения нужно угадать?

И гляньте хотя бы сюда: http://dedicatesupport.com/archives/52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И после нескольких упорных часов понимания непонимания, ответ:
В Ubuntu впрочем как и в других ОС есть переменные окружения и когда запускаешь что-то с консоли это одно, но всё совсем другое когда как-то что-то запускает с браузера.

И я запуская через браузер получал кучу ошибок типа не опредена такая-то переменная.

Поэтому т.к. мне было без разницы, как запустить это чудесную прогу, я написал

```
echo '----------------------------------';
$output = shell_exec('./run.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

и в run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

export MRT_HOME=/home/divr/geolocal/bin

export MRT_DATA_DIR=/home/diver/geolocal/data

PATH=$PATH:/home/divr/geolocal/bin

./resample -p ./convert.prm
```

собственно тут всё должно быть понятно, конечно это далеко не самое хорошее решения, но мне именно так и нужно в силу некоторых причин. На питоне в принципе можно переписать и от шелла отказаться.

Comment: если что то в subprocess.Popen есть параметр env, который принимает словарь перменных среды